# How parse xml that contains multiple variables in pl/sql developer

Tags: xml, parsing, plsqldeveloper

I stuck in parsing xml document that contains multiple variables. PL/SQL does not show any problem but I get null answer.

```
<inputVariable>
<part xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" name="payload">
<SomethingProcessRequest xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema- 
instance" xmlns:ns2="http://xmlns.oracle.com/SomethingProcess" 
xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/SomethingProcess1">
<ns2:p_a xsi:nil="">1</ns2:p_a>
<ns2:p_b xsi:nil="">1</ns2:p_b>
<ns2:p_c xsi:nil="">1</ns2:p_c>
<ns2:p_d xsi:nil="">1</ns2:p_d>
</SomethingProcessRequest>
</part>
</inputVariable>
```

Here below is the script

```
SELECT xt.*
FROM   XML_DATA x, 
XMLTABLE(XMLNAMESPACES('http://xmlns.oracle.com/SomethingProcess1',
'http://xmlns.oracle.com/SomethingProcess' AS "ns2")           
       '/inputVariable>/part/SomethingProcessRequest' PASSING x.cdetails
       COLUMNS 
          stag        varchar2(200)  PATH 'name(.)',
          cvalues     varchar2(2000)  PATH '.'
       ) xt
where x.cikey=123 and x.slabel='input'
```

What is the problem with this script?